# Understanding Foucalt's reasoning when describing Palazzo's work

Tags: foucault

In Foucault's lecture series "Security, Territory and Population", in the lecture of 15 March 1978, Foucault traces what is understood by the concept of raison d'État, starting with Palazzo's work entitled Discourse on government and the true raison d'État. Below is an extract of what Foucault writes:

> Well, “raison” is a word used in two senses: Raison is the entire essence of a thing, which constitutes the union, the combination of all its parts; it is the necessary bond between the different elements that constitute a thing. That is raison. But “raison” is also employed in another sense. Subjectively, raison is a certain power of the soul that enables it to know the truth of things, that is to say, precisely that bond, that integrity of the different parts that constitutes a thing."

If I understand correctly, the first meaning of raison is the very essence of thing that forms unity, which is the same, according to Foucault, as the necessary connection/bond between the elements to form unity(in that case, this essence is connection/bond)

In the second sense, it is the capacity of the soul to see this connection/bond (because "the truth of things" in this context is connection/bond)

However, Foucault then writes:

> Raison is therefore a means of knowledge, but it is also something that allows the will to adjust itself to what it knows, that is to say to adjust itself to the very essence of things"

1. I understand, how it is a "means of knowledge". It goes along with the second definition about the ability of the soul to see/understand the bond.
2. What is the word "will" doing here? Is it the the synonim to the word "soul"? If so, what does "adjust" mean in that context?

Then Foucalt writes:

> So raison will be the essence of things, knowledge of the reason of things, and that kind of force that enables, and up to a point obliges [the will] to go to the very essence of things. So much for the definition of the word "raison"."

1. Okay, raison is essence in accordance with the first definition of raison.
2. How is it knowledge of the reason of things itself, when it is the ability of the soul to know the reason of things (according to second definition of raison)?
3. Again, what is with the raison being the "force, that enables will to go to the very essence of things". Where does this conclusion come from?

Comment: Maybe related to [Practical Reason](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/practical-reason/): "the general human capacity for resolving, through reflection, the question of what one is to do."